# Reading a file line by line and capturing that lines word

Tags: c, file, io, fgets

I am trying to read through a text file line by line and with each line I am trying to assign each word to a list. Do something with that list. After I do this, I am going go to the next line.

```
#define BUFSIZE 1000
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char buf[BUFSIZE]; 
    FILE* fp;
    fp=fopen(argv[1], "r"); //open the file

    while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZE-1, fp)!= NULL){ //loop through each line of the file
        char *myargs[5];
        myargs[0]= ??   //some way to set the first word to this 

        myargs[4]= ??   //there will only be 4 words
        myargs[5]=NULL; 


        //do something with myargs
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest looking at `strtok()` library function

Comment: Note: `-1` not needed in `fgets(buf, BUFSIZE-1, fp)`.  Use `fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, fp)` or better `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fp=fopen(argv[1], "r");`  Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameters were actually entered by the user.  If not entered, then output a `USAGE` message to `stderr` and exit the program

Comment: OT: regarding: `fp=fopen(argv[1], "r");`  When calling C library functions (all of which can fail) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call: `perror( "my error message"); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strtok` to separate a line of text into tokens.  Assuming each word is separated by a space, you can do the following:

```
while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZE-1, fp)!= NULL){ //loop through each line of the file
    char *myargs[4] = { NULL }; 
    char *p;
    int i, count = 0;

    p = strtok(buf, " ");
    while (p && (count < 4)) {
        myargs[count++] = strdup(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    // operate on myargs

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        free(myargs[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Each line has the same amount of words, would this still be the best practice?